# MapBox gl js, Browser console security Error

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm using Mapbox gl js into a website to show safari's map. I created my mapbox account and my API token and i'm experiencing a browser error:

SecurityError: The operation is insecure. cecb579d-d0ad-424a-9e7d-bf4c7353d904:1

If i try to open the source debug blob i get a blank page :(

Thx in advance

here is the code:

````
    <html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />   
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@turf/turf@6/turf.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<div class="overlay">
<button id="replay">Replay</button>
</div>
<!-- here i used the defoult API key -->
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxleDk1IiwiYSI6ImNrcTRlajRrajE3cnIydnFyMGMwN3cyeG4ifQ.jU5odECEGnFPWjflz37KhA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [36, -1],
            zoom: 7.3
        });
        // 1 Nairobi, Kenya
        var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({           
            color: "#737C56",
            draggable: false
        })
        .setLngLat([36.70, -1.30])
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
            className: 'pop-up',
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: true
        })
        .setText('Nairobi, Kenya'))
        .addTo(map);

        // 2 The Great Rift Valley View Point, B 3, Kenya
        var marker2 = new mapboxgl.Marker({           
            color: "#737C56",
            draggable: false
        })
        .setLngLat([36.58, -1.08])
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
            className: 'pop-up',
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: true
        })
        .setText('The Great Rift Valley View Point, B 3, Kenya')) 
        .addTo(map);
        [...]
 </script>
 </body>
 <html> ```
````

Comment: Have you tried adding only the map to your project without adding those markers?

Comment: not yet, i 'm going to try. Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

I've removed some scripts from your code and it seems to work fine. please refer to this [link](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/JjNdNqz?editors=1111)

```
<html lang="it">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.3.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    </head>
<body>

<div id="map"></div>
<div class="overlay">
<button id="replay">Replay</button>
</div>
<!-- here i used the defoult API key -->
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWxleDk1IiwiYSI6ImNrcTRlajRrajE3cnIydnFyMGMwN3cyeG4ifQ.jU5odECEGnFPWjflz37KhA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: [36, -1],
            zoom: 7.3
        });
        // 1 Nairobi, Kenya
        var marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({           
            color: "#737C56",
            draggable: false
        })
        .setLngLat([36.70, -1.30])
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
            className: 'pop-up',
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: true
        })
        .setText('Nairobi, Kenya'))
        .addTo(map);

        // 2 The Great Rift Valley View Point, B 3, Kenya
        var marker2 = new mapboxgl.Marker({           
            color: "#737C56",
            draggable: false
        })
        .setLngLat([36.58, -1.08])
        .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({
            className: 'pop-up',
            closeButton: false,
            closeOnClick: true
        })
        .setText('The Great Rift Valley View Point, B 3, Kenya')) 
        .addTo(map);
 </script>
 </body>
 <html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Max.  I see you removed the turf js but actually i can still see that browser error alert: The Operation is insecure. Is it about the default API key or there's something else missing in my code? Thx in advance for your precious help. 
Emanuele